# How to architect a project which has more number of dynamic pages in laravel

Tags: laravel, codeigniter, database-design

I have a project which has a large number of dynamic pages. Approximately 30+ pages. The content of each page is different. what I did is created 30 tables and 30 routes as well. And on the admin side, there are 30+ modules to edit the contents. Is it the right way to do this?. In database table, different columns has to be kept.

```
// Route definition...
Route::get('/page1', [Page1Controller::class, 'show']);
Route::get('/page2', [Page2Controller::class, 'show']);
Route::get('/page3', [Page3Controller::class, 'show']);

// Controller method definition...
public function index() {
    return view('page1');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Route definition...
// All other routes above this slug catch all. otherwise it will try and hit this controller all the time and fail.
Route::get('/{slug}', [PageController::class, 'show']);

// Controller method definition...
public function show($slug)
{
    $contents = PageContents::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    if ($contents) {
        return view('page')->with('contents', $contents);
    }

    return view('404');
}
```

This way you have a table with all the contents you need. e.g. title, body copy so on. but if each layout is different you could also return a different view. e.g.

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $contents = PageContents::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    if ($contents) {
        return view('page-'.$slug)->with('contents', $contents);
    }

    return view('404');
}
```

Comment: some page has 3 column data like.. title, subtitle, heading1... Another page might have 10.  The table columns may vary for different pages. So do i need to create one table for all the pages and left null for columns if the page doesn't require that particular column data while editing the page from admin side?. In admin side also I have to create that much number of pages for edit feature. right?

Comment: You could have it as a related table, e.g. PageContents as a table containing essentials and then have a related Sections table. its all up to you. I Personally would just hard code something like this. no need to re create a CMS.

Answer (score 1):

You can create only one controller and add a parameter in the route(web.php):

`web.php`

```
//---Route Definition
Route::get('page/{page_number}', [PageController::class, 'show'])->name('page.show');
```

`PageController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

class PageController extends Controller {
    //---Show
    public function show($page_number) {
        return view('show.show', compact('page_number'));
    }//---End of Function show
}
```

If you want to retrieve your data from a database just one table is enough, just create a `page` table and give a field by the name of `page_number` and retrieve your specific page data by the given field.

**For example:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

class PageController extends Controller {
    //---Show
    public function show($page_number) {
        $page = PageContent::where('page_number', $page_number)->first();
        return view('show.show', compact('page'));
    }//---End of Function show
}
```

**

**Your Link to routes**

```
<a href="{{ route('page.show', ['page_number' => 1])) }}" class="" title="Show">
    Show
</a>
```

Comment: some page has 3 column data like.. title, subtitle, heading1... Another page might have 10.  The table columns may vary for different pages. So do i need to create one table for all the pages and left null for columns if the page doesn't require that particular column data while editing the page from admin side?. In admin side also I have to create that much number of pages for edit feature. right?

Comment: See if you do not have that many changes on all your pages, create one table, for those fields you can use `nullable()` in your migration, I think it is better to use one table, manage all your pages.